# Why does my search function take much longer after rearranging it to save a few checks?

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a Sub which looks for the Search Terms from one sheet, and captures each line from a big array of strings which contains one of those terms (printing it to another sheet).

Originally I had it written like this:

- For each Search Term, look at each line in the file and print each match.

It worked, but it meant that if one line contained multiple Search Terms, it would get printed as many times.  I wanted to eliminate that, just printing the line once if it contained at least one Search Term.  So, I rearranged the code to work like this:

- For each line in the file, look at each Search Term and print the line if it matches.
- (and if you do get a match, skip the remaining Search Terms for that line)

If anything, this way should be slightly more efficient than the original, I thought...
And yet, after I rearranged the code, it takes **much longer** to execute.

I guess this means that, though I feel as though I'm doing the same things in a different order, and even saving some unnecessary checks, I must be somehow compounding the parts that take the longest.  Can anyone shed some light and help me understand how I've made the code so much worse?

Here's what the two versions of the relevant code segment look like:

**Original way:**

```
searchTermRow = firstSearchTermRow
While ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("SearchTerms").Cells(searchTermRow, 1) <> ""
    term = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("SearchTerms").Cells(searchTermRow, 1)
    For j = 1 To UBound(bigStringArray) - 1
        counter = counter + 1
        If (InStr(bigStringArray(j), term) <> 0) Then
            Cells(resultsRow, 1).Value = bigStringArray(j)
            resultsRow = resultsRow + 1
        End If
    Next j
    searchTermRow = searchTermRow + 1
Wend
```

**Rearranged:**

```
For j = 1 To UBound(bigStringArray) - 1
    searchTermRow = firstSearchTermRow
    Do While ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("SearchTerms").Cells(searchTermRow, 1) <> ""
        term = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("SearchTerms").Cells(searchTermRow, 1)
        counter = counter + 1
        If (InStr(bigStringArray(j), term) <> 0) Then
            Cells(resultsRow, 1).Value = bigStringArray(j)
            resultsRow = resultsRow + 1
            Exit Do
        End If
        searchTermRow = searchTermRow + 1
    Loop
Next j
```

bigStringArray is a large array of strings which consists of every line from a file.
counter is just there so that I could count how many checks were done.

Comment: Reading from the sheet takes the time  ie `term = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("SearchTerms").Cells(searchTermRow, 1)` so in the first example you do this only x times (where x is the number of search terms). In the second example  you are executing that code by at least UBound(bigStringArray) times and probabaly x/2 times that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do one pass through the `bigStringArray` by using a regular expression with a pattern such as `term1|term2|term3 etc`.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub RegexMatch()

    Const firstSearchTermRow = 2

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, resultsRow As Long, j As Long
    Dim rngTerms As Range, t0 As Single: t0 = Timer

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("SearchTerms")
    lastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
 
    ' build regex pattern
    Dim sPattern As String
    Set rngTerms = ws.Range("A" & firstSearchTermRow & ":A" & lastRow)
    sPattern = Join(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(rngTerms), "|")
    'Debug.Print sPattern

    Dim regex As Object, m As Object
    Set regex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With regex
       .Global = False
       .MultiLine = False
       .IgnoreCase = True
       .Pattern = "(" & sPattern & ")"
    End With

    ' test data
    Dim bigStringArray
    bigStringArray = Array("", "ABCDE", "BCDEF", "CDEFGH", "DEFHIJKL")

    resultsRow = 1
    For j = 1 To UBound(bigStringArray)
        If regex.test(bigStringArray(j)) Then
            Set m = regex.Execute(bigStringArray(j)) ' match
            Cells(resultsRow, 1).Value = bigStringArray(j)
            Cells(resultsRow, 2).Value = m(0) ' matched term
            resultsRow = resultsRow + 1
        End If
    Next

    MsgBox j - 1 & " strings checked", vbInformation, Format(Timer - t0, "0.00 secs")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this - I appreciate you sharing what is probably a better method than either of mine.  When I get a chance I will try this out.

Comment: I'm marking this as the accepted answer, but I think the answer to my question is what you shared in a comment:
"Reading from the sheet takes the time ie term = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("SearchTerms").Cells(searchTermRow, 1) so in the first example you do this only x times (where x is the number of search terms). In the second example you are executing that code by at least UBound(bigStringArray) times and probabaly x/2 times that."
Thanks again!

Comment: @Mindgames If you copy the search terms range into an array and loop through that then I would expect the 2 methods to have similar performance.